# Windows 10 automatic restart

Tags: windows-10

On my Lenovo IdeaPad 3, Windows is stuck in a restart loop. I cant access settinga or task manager,only bios and cmd. How do I fix it? I have tried everything and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

> On my Lenovo IdeaPad 3, Windows is stuck in a restart loop. I cant
> access settinga or task manager,only bios and cmd. How do I fix it? I
> have tried everything and nothing seems to work.

When this happens, there are two predominate reasons:

**1.** Windows is so badly damaged that the machine will not restart.

Solution:  Take the disk out, recover your data, and reinstall Windows. Then  restore your data.

If you are adept with bootable USB Keys, and can ensure Secure Boot is disabled, you can boot with a Windows USB and try to recover files on another USB drive.

You may need a local shop to help you with this.

**2.** The drive is damaged.

Solution: Replace the drive and then see if a local agency can recover data from the damaged drive.